# Assigning User Assigned Identity to Azure VMSS fails

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-managed-identity, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a VMSS resource linked to a Service Fabric cluster. I have modified the ARM templates to have user managed identity for VMSS.

```
"variables": {                      
"vmssApiVersion": "2017-03-30",
...
..
}
....
"resources": [
{
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
"apiVersion": "[variables('vmssApiVersion')]",
"name": "[concat(variables('vmssNamePrefix'),
...
...
"identity": {​​​​​​
    "type": "UserAssigned",
    "identityIds": [
     "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<usrasgid>"       
    ]                     
}​​​​​​
.....
.....
}
]
```

While deploying, it throws the error

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidParameter",
        "target": "resourceIdentity.type",
        "message": "ResourceIdentity Type must be provided and set to \"SystemAssigned\"."
    }
}
```

Why does it ask me to set managed identity to SystemAssigned? How can I set it to user managed identity?

Comment: Hello, @krr, can you please try using the latest api version which is `2021-07-01` with schema version `"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#"` and see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I followed this. It seems supported in older version too.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-template-windows-vmss#user-assigned-managed-identity

Comment: let me test it out with older version and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the old versions and seems only `SystemAssigned` is allowed in API Version `2017-03-30`. But , It was successful when I used `2018-06-01`. So , as a Solution you can use the below to resolve the issue:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
    "name": "ansumantestvmss",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "identity": {
        "type": "userAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
            "[resourceID('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/','ansumanmdid')]" : {}
        }
    },
    "properties":{}
}    
]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found the documentation as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2017-03-30/virtualmachinescalesets?tabs=json The identity is set to SystemAssigned in the old Api version.